# Why does the social icon does not show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
        body{
      
              font-family:Montserrat;
         }
        .navbar, .dropdown-menu{
         background:#44c763;
         border:none;
        border-radius:10px;
        }
    
          .nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,      .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li{
      border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    }
    .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover,.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
      border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
      background: none;
    }
    .navbar a, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-toggle{
     color: #fff;
    }
    .dropdown-menu{
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
    
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+1), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+1){
      border-bottom: #4011E8 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+2), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+2){
      border-bottom: #F3937D 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+3), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+3){
      border-bottom: #FC3665 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+4), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+4){
      border-bottom: #F9D86F 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+5), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+5){
      border-bottom: #0FFA08 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+6), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+6){
      border-bottom: #D1F9DF 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+7), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+7){
      border-bottom: #FF748C 5px double;
    }
    .nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+8), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+8){
      border-bottom: #FFF078 5px double;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
        color: #fff;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .social {
      width: 90%;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
    
    }
    
    ul.social-icons li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    ul.social-icons li a {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: url("../images/img-sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    }
    ul.social-icons li a.facebook {
      background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    
    ul.social-icons li a.facebook:hover {
      background-position: 0px -50px;
    }
    
    
    
    ul.social-icons li a.instagram {
      background-position: -150px 0px;
    }
    
    ul.social-icons li a.instagram:hover {
      background-position: -150px -50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                           
                            <li class=" dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
                                   aria-expanded="false">About us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
                                           aria-expanded="false">Residential</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Office</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Mixed Use</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                           
                             <li><a href="#" class="">Products</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" class="">Gallery</a></li>
                              
          </li>
                           
          </ul>
                    
                      
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
             <li class=""><a href="#">kunalyadav@gmail.com</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">984987454225</a></li>
                            
            <li class="connect-social">
              
             
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/deshaengineers"  class="facebook" title="Go to Our Facebook Page"></a></li>
                
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/desha-engineers-india-pvt-ltd"  class="linkedin" title="Go to Our Linkedin Page"></a></li>
                
              
            </li>
          </li>
                           
                           
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have added the code to show social icons in the nav bar, but the image for icons is not shown, if hovered on the area it shows that it is clickable but image does not loads. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't have anything inside of the href tags for your media links. In this [codepen link](http://codepen.io/bonzo/pen/JKVyRN?editors=1000), specifically on line 150 I added in an example image for the linkedin icon.

```
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/desha-engineers-india-pvt-ltd"  class="linkedin" title="Go to Our Linkedin Page"><img src="http://static2.intelimedia.pl/sub/Narysuj-sobie-Gonka-w17896.jpg" style="height:30px;"></a></li>
```

Comment: It works now, I am accepting this answer. However can you tell me how to the image when hovered?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I am asking about the hover effect, i want the image to roll over

Comment: If you're looking for on-hover examples from css, hopefully [this example by Naoya](https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/ZYNOBZ) might help. If you wanted the image to flip, check out lines 100-105 in the HTML, and 141-147 in the CSS. Otherwise I'm real sorry but I'm not sure what exact hover effect you're asking for.

Comment: this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

change some CSS & HTML

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class=" dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
                               aria-expanded="false">About us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=" dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
                                       aria-expanded="false">Residential</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Office</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Mixed Use</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                         <li><a href="#" class="">Products</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
         <li class=""><a href="#">kunalyadav@gmail.com</a></li>
         <li class=""><a href="#">984987454225</a></li>



            <li class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/deshaengineers"  class="facebook" title="Go to Our Facebook Page"></a></li>

            <li class="social"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/desha-engineers-india-pvt-ltd"  class="linkedin" title="Go to Our Linkedin Page"></a></li>
</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{

          font-family:Montserrat;
     }
    .navbar, .dropdown-menu{
     background:#44c763;
     border:none;
    border-radius:10px;
    }

      .nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,      .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li{
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover,.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  background: none;
}
.navbar a, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-toggle{
 color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+1), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+1){
  border-bottom: #4011E8 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+2), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+2){
  border-bottom: #F3937D 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+3), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+3){
  border-bottom: #FC3665 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+4), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+4){
  border-bottom: #F9D86F 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+5), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+5){
  border-bottom: #0FFA08 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+6), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+6){
  border-bottom: #D1F9DF 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+7), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+7){
  border-bottom: #FF748C 5px double;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+8), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+8){
  border-bottom: #FFF078 5px double;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
}
.social {
  width: 90%;
   text-align: left;

}

ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.social a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("../images/img-sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
li.social a.facebook {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

li.social a.facebook:hover {
  background-position: 0px -50px;
}



li.social a.instagram {
  background-position: -150px 0px;
}

li.social a.instagram:hover {
  background-position: -150px -50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7pycxo8k/3/

Comment: What did you change, why did you change it, and how does it fix the issue?

Comment: where this class define in html code "social-icons"

Comment: I'm not digging through hundreds of lines of code to find the one thing you changed. And your answer doesn't help anyone, even if it does solve the problem, because "give me teh codez" is not an attitude to encourage.